# How do I activate the debugger in CS-Cart?

Tags: cs-cart

How do I activate the debugger in CS Cart?

I've done this:

http://docs.cs-cart.com/4.2.x/tools/debugger.html#activate-debug-mode

i.e added the debug term while logged into the Administrator panel.

Update:

actually I'm using v 4.1.4 but the documentation is still the same.

No joy.

What else do I have to do?

Answer (score 1):

If you set DEBUG_MODE to true in your config.php, and clear the cache, it will enable the debug bar.

Did you clear your cache? (`path-to-your-site.com/your-admin.php?cc&ctpl`)

Answer (score 0):

Go to ***config.php*** file in your cs-cart root folder and uncomment below line

// Uncomment to enable the developer tools: debugger, PHP and SQL loggers, etc.

```
// define('DEBUG_MODE', true);
```

// Uncomment to enable error reporting.

```
// define('DEVELOPMENT', true);
```